# How to create a form with address autocomplete in flutter ? not interested to see points or map - it is only for register page

Tags: flutter, google-places-autocomplete

Hello guys I am new at flutter and building register page for my app. I have the following issue when I try to use below code in form field Someone can help me please ?

> The instance member 'kGoogleApiKey' can't be accessed in an initializer.

[image: he instance member 'kGoogleApiKey' can't be accessed in an initializer]

I am currently using last version of flutter, flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0 and geocoder: ^0.2.1

Comment: Hi @213Lord, please upload code and not image of code as it is really difficult to view and replicate from the image.

Answer (score 1):

Move the following line inside the `initState()` method and declaring the variable as `late`:
late final GoogleMapsPlaces _places;

```dart
late GoogleMapPlaces _places;

@override
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  _places = GoogleMapPlaces(apiKey: kGoogleApiKey)
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Sorry but were should I place the  Void initState.. ? and late is not recognized telling me it's a text.. thank you for your help

Comment: Inside the `_RegisterScreen2State` class

Comment: sorry. again to ask you. this @Mayank but still facing an issue The method 'GoogleMapPlaces' isn't defined for the type '_RegisterScreen2State'.

AND late is not recognized as error below 

Unexpected text 'late' :   late GoogleMapsPlaces _places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);

Comment: @213Lord I can't help you beyond as I don't know your entire code and how you have organised it. But I think you should go over the [Dart language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour), as this will help you understand the basics of dart better and wil help you in understanding the code and error better.